# Read contents of a directory in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to spark just wanted to know how can we read contents of a directory and iterate over them. C# corresponding code

```
Foreach(var path in Directory. EnumerateFiles(directory, *,.. ) {} ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>   JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);
>   JavaPairRDD<String,String> rdd = jsc.wholeTextFiles(path);
>           for(Tuple2<String, String> str : rdd.toArray()) {           System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
>       System.out.println("File name " + str._1);
>       System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
>       System.out.println();
>       System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
>       System.out.println("content " + str._2);
>       System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
>   }
> ```

Hope it helps, I had the same question.